# How to make this user interface

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to learn how to develop Flutter application and I want to know how to make user interface in Flutter like what is shown in the picture [image: java]

[image]

Comment: You can either use `GridView`, `Wrap`, `Table` etc

Comment: You should avoid asking questions like this without mentioning what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to just give you the code to make this UI, but I'll help you. I'd recommend a `GridView` with a crossAxisCount of 3 so you can align the buttons like this. Then I'd separate out the 0 button and surround it with a `Center` widget so that it's centered.

If you're just learning, I suggest making simple UIs first to get a grasp of how the framework works, then you can move to intermediate UIs like this one.

Comment: thank youbut i tryed to do it my self but i had a bad result it's shown in a different picture the buttons are too big and it didn't look beautiful i tryed to change their size but making them in a container or a sized box but no result